# How to make an image in button?

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I'm newbie in this site, but I have a question.
This is my code in Tkinter. My problem is that when I go to put an image inside a button, it does not display it.
Only in this program, because if I write the same things in a new clean file, it works. What's the problem ?

```
def newWindow():

root.destroy()    #this destroy the main window
window = Tk()     
window.title("Provisory title")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.geometry("420x430")

#BUTTON 
bt3 = Button(window)

#BUTTON POSITIONING
bt3.place(x = 10, y = 10)

#image button
calc = PhotoImage(file= "icon_Calculator.png")
bt3.config(image = calc, width="100",height="100")
```

Comment: It is because you use local variable `calc` to hold the image and `calc` will be destroyed when `newwindow()` function returns.  Change `calc` to `bt3.calc`.

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. If the problem is with a button, we don't need eleven buttons to illustrate the problem.

Comment: You right! I keep it in mind! @BryanOakley

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!  @acw1668