# image on button using Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to put an image on a button using Tkinter gui, but instead of the photo, the button is a white square.
im using these lines:

```
button = tk.Button(self.root, height=100, width=165, 
                   text=name_to_teach_command, command=action_with_args)
st = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=photo_location)
button.config(image=st)
button.configure(relief=FLAT)
```

thanks for help!

Comment: It is because local variable `st` is used to hold the image which will be destroyed once the function exits.  This kind of question has already been answered dozens of time.

Comment: @acw1668 has already answered an almost exact duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815388/how-to-make-an-image-in-button

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is may be due to the size of the image.Tkinter doesn't make the image to fit in space, you have to adjust its size.
And you can also make some change in your code:

```
st = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=photo_location)
button = tk.Button(self.root, height=100, width=165, 
                   image= st, command=action_with_args)
button.configure(relief=FLAT)
```

Hope it will help!